# Infinite loop when redefining the setter of a property

Tags: objective-c, properties

In Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X (Hillegass), there is a class in chapter 19:

```
@interface BigLetterView : NSView {
NSColor *bgColor;
}
@property (strong) NSColor *bgColor;
@end
```

The accessor is defined like this:

```
- (void)setBgColor:(NSColor *)c {
bgColor = c;
[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]; }
```

This looked correct to me, but it creates an infinite loop: `bgColor = c` calls `setBgColor:c`

Is this code correct ?

How to redefine a setter? What do I need to compile this code ?

Comment: "`bgColor = c;` calls `setBgColor:c`" - no, it doesn't, you probably meant `self.bgColor = c;`...

Comment: If it makes a problem then just make sure the name of the ivar is different than the property. If you use bgColor for property, then use _bgColor for the ivar. It makes the code clear and you could prevent such conditions.

Comment: if you want us to help to debug your code, give us the real shit. this definitely has no infinite loop. probably you are setting  bgColor inside the setter as `self.bgColor = c;`. Also fix the formatting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern Xcode/llvm you can clean up your code a bit.

Namely you dont need to declare neither a member variable as backing variable, nor a synthesize statement.

If you dont declase synthesize your self, a property `foo` will have the backing variable `_foo`

So this code should work

```
@interface BigLetterView : NSView 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSColor *bgColor;
@end

@implementation BigLetterView
@synthesize bgColor = _bgColor;

- (void)setBgColor:(NSColor *)c 
{
    _bgColor = c;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES]; 
}
@end
```

Comment: But now I have: Setter and getter must both be synthesized, or both be user defined,or the property must be nonatomic. How would the bgColor look like in this case ? _bgColor becomes an undeclared variable in both functions with: -(NSColor *) bgColor {return _bgColor;}

Comment: Not really: this is Version 4.5.2 (4G2008a)

Comment: Are you compiling with llvm or gcc?

Comment: I'm using Apple LLVM 4.1. I'll try to extract a minimal code that reproduces what I was complaining about, because the code is actual code I compiled and runned, and I had not used self dot bgColor. Anyway I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way which looks cleaner and better to understand.

```
@interface BigLetterView : NSView
@property (strong) NSColor *bgColor;
@end
@implementation BigLetterView

- (void)setBgColor:(NSColor *)c {
_bgColor = c;
[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]; 
}
```

Also, make a simple rule to always use the property with self in any other places you use it. It is just a better rule for making you understand things clearly.

Comment: Note, that declaring synthesize is not needed anymore.

Comment: and the declaration of the member isnt needed anymore too

Comment: Yes, it doesn't require in newer objective c, but it is infact easy to understand what is going on. What does synthesize do to the original property and the accessor variable

Comment: the backing variable of property foo will be available as _foo.

Comment: Ha ha now, its done. Is there anything else ? Please do correct if you find any typo. I dont mean to show the new and a better syntax but just wanted to put the idea how it goes.

Comment: yeah, you just introduced a new typo — in the very beginning

Comment: ha ha thanks. I am kind of flattered now. It is you who made me nervous to make mistake.